# Your first guess is wrong

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

I saw a puzzle I liked and wanted to make a less trivial version. Here it is, find the odd one out.

1. Below
2. Blot
3. Chips
4. demos
5. First
6. Gloss
7. Begin
8. Pages

Comment: And here I was second guessing myself...

Comment: Ok, someone's got to say it: #4, demos is, since it's the only one that doesn't start with a capital. You said find *the* odd one out; I've found *an* odd one out, and hence, assuming the question is well-posed, found *the* odd one out. (How has this been on 15hrs and no-one said this yet?? =P)

Comment: @SamT See title.

Comment: How do you know that was my first guess? My standard guess for odd-one-out questions is the first one: it's the unique one that is first in the list, and hence if the question is well-posed it must be the odd-one-out, haha! =P

Comment: @SamT : Bah!  It's always the second one -- because 2 is the oddest prime.

Comment: @EricTowers -- that is one of the best comments I've ever seen on SE! I'm definitely stealing that for future use =P

Comment: @EricTowers imho 2 is the evenest prime ;-P

Comment: @Scz : Nah...  After the ones tied for last place, it's only the second least even prime.

Comment: The title says that if you guess "First", then you're wrong. So of the remaining, "demos" is the most distinctive.

Comment: "odd one" - while redundant, that's *1. Below* ;-D

Comment: @LSerni Can't argue with that.

Comment: @Acccumulation I think to deliberately avoid that misconception, the OP has ordered the words around to say *your first guess* instead.

Comment: According to the answers below, the word **7.** ***Begin*** has he most odd-one-out properties than the others. Does this make that the true odd one out?

Comment: @user477343 No, the intended answer is a combination of Steven Irrgang's answer plus yjo's addition as a fix.

Comment: The level of arbitrariness is very arbitrary. That's what makes this puzzle so hard, and maybe not so great (through no fault of the puzzle maker).

Comment: @ErikE I'm surprised at how well the puzzle held up, to be honest. There were a couple of mismatches, but even with those in mind the overall idea was understood fairly quickly and there were no guesses for the unintended answer beyond Nathan Peters' and Phylyp's, neither of which were very compelling given they weren't sets for the other 7 elements. Maybe it's just bias but I'm happy with how it went.

Comment: I agree it turned out better than might be expected. But there has to be some more objective way to create a puzzle like this. I mean, for example, *Below* is the only word that has a *w* in it, and is the only word with an unpronounced letter, and is the only preposition. Why are none of these important? Someone could create a wikipedia article tomorrow about words with *w's* in them. I'm not saying it's a bad puzzle, just maybe I'm saying it's not a satisfying puzzle to me because of the arbitrariness.

Comment: @ErikE If people think a Wikipedia article about words *without* "w" in them is an important thing to write, I'll be happy to reconsider my position on it ;). Remember that you define the odd one out by talking about the set that the other members fall into.

Comment: There IS an article, [Preposition](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition), which has the word *Below* in it. We already had one set that was a mix of two properties ("begins with" *or* "ends with"). Why does that one get to be two things? Can there be three? Is there an article about words that begin or end with those two specific letters? I mean, all the other words are verbs, nouns, or adverbs. A class of three things isn't much different from a class of two things, and the class of three things are all individually in Wikipedia, but the class of two things aren't.

Comment: @ErikE The fact Steven's answer still has that mix of two properties aspect is the only reason why I haven't accepted it! You're right that it fails the arbitrariness test; yjo's addition corrects it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok I think I have an overall answer that I'm happy with all the steps of:

> The answer is 1 Below, because every other word is the odd one out in a compelling conventional sense.
>
>  The specific rules for which each other word is the odd one out:
>  2: Every word except "Blot"(4 letters) has 5 letters
>  3: Every word except "Chips" has an anagram (Elbow, Bolt, modes, Rifts, Slogs, Being, Gapes)
>  4: Every word except "demos" is capitalised
>  5: Every word except "First" ends with a different word (low, lot, hips, emos, loss, gin, ages)
>  6: Every word except "Gloss" has unique letters
>  7: Every word except "Begin" is sorted alphabetically in the list
>  8: Every word except "Pages" has its letters in alphabetical order
>
>  Credit where it's due: votbear #8, TheOmegaPostulate for #6, yjo for the correct #5. The others I got myself independently, although I believe I was beaten to some of them by other people.
>
>  I get the same answer in the end as votbear has but I think my justifications are better (they may also think theirs are better of course). In particular now as of this edit I believe they're all the intended answers, based on feedback from the creator. I've tried to phrase each as a positive property of the other words since odd-one-out only makes sense if there's a compelling and unlikely common property among the other words. In that sense #6 is questionable but the rest are great.

Previous answer/working for posterity:

Ok I think I know *how* to solve it, and I want to get in early...

> I think that there's an odd-one-out property for every word in the list
>  except one, and that one is the solution.
>
>  So far, I can eliminate:
>  4. demos has a lower case starting letter
>  2. Blot has 4 letters
>  7. Begin is out of order in the otherwise alphabetical listing
>  8. Pages has letters not in alphabetical order (I got this from votbear's answer)
>
>  That leaves 1, 3, 5 and 6.
>  
>  Edit 1: Chips is the only one which does not have an anagram. Down to 1, 5 and 6.
>  Edit 2: Begin is the only word for which you can't make a new word by removing one letter. And I've just realised that I'd already eliminated it. Well it's knocked out twice now. Maybe there's a slighly different rule with the ordering instead?
>  Edit 3: "All the words except Gloss have unique letters". Nearly said 5 unique letters but "Blot" doesn't. I saw this in votbear's answer and I'm coming around to it being good enough. So I'm down to 1 and 5, with some slight discomfort over there being two good reasons for Begin.

Comment: Ah, that's a nice line of thinking... rot13(gur bqq bar bhg vf gur bayl bar abg) !

Comment: #6 possibly rot13(bayl bar jvgu n ercrngrq yrggre)

Comment: I don't want to give you #5 because it breaks [the arbitrariness rule](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62148/your-first-guess-is-wrong/62220#comment189627_62150). Your initial #7 was the intended one, but I'm happy with either. I am surprised the final part is as difficult as it is, given I've already given the clue that rot13(vg'f irel fvzvyne gb erzbivat gur svefg yrggre naq purpxvat jurgure gur erznvavat cneg vf n jbeq). Show how hard estimating difficulty can be :/.

Comment: Every word but #5 rot13(pbagnvaf n fhssvk juvpu vf nyfb n jbeq)

Comment: @yjo That is the intended final answer. Congrats on completing the puzzle :).

Comment: Ok, I was bothered by the similarity between #5 and #7 and figured only at most one of them was the right one. I just picked the wrong one to keep. Answer should have all the right rules now.

Answer (score 36):

Edit: [Steven's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62153/41007) seems to be in the right direction, so here's my updated answer:

> It seems that 7 of the 8 words have a property that makes them the 'odd one out', and we're looking for the one that doesn't have such a property.
>
>  1. Below - ?
>
>  2. Blot - The only one that doesn't have 5 letters. (From [Matthew](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62152/41007) and [Steven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62153/41007))
>
>  3. Chips - The only one that doesn't have an anagram. (Found by [Rupert](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62155/41007))
>  All other words: Elbow, Bolt, Modes, Frits, Slogs, Being, Gapes
>
>  4. demos - The only one that doesn't start with a capital letter.
>
>  5. First - The only one with 3 consecutive consonants?
>
>  6. Gloss - The only one with a duplicate letter.
>
>  7. Begin - The only one in this list that doesn't follow the alphabetical order of the items,
>  OR the only one that cannot be turned into another word by removing one letter. (From [Steven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62153/41007))
>  All other words: Blow, Lot, Hips, Demo, Fist, Loss, Page
>
>  8. Pages - The only one whose letters are not in alphabetical order.

As such, it seems the best fit for the final answer would be

> 1. Below.
>  Of course, with increasingly convoluted rules you will eventually find a way to make this word the odd one out instead. But I think this set of answers provide the simplest, most straightforward rules for all the other words.

Comment: You're pretty much there. There's a minor thing I'd like to clear up, though. Try to solve an odd one out by looking at properties that everything has *except* one, not properties that are unique to a particular element. rot13(Engure guna fnlvat bayl Oybg unf sbhe yrggref, fnl gung rirel jbeq rkprcg Oybg unf svir yrggref.)

Comment: Below is the only word that is made up of two other words (Be, Low). And chips is the only word that is an object that is a source of food. I guess every word has an odd-one-out property. However, that is the definition of chips, and every definition of each word is unique, apart from the words *Begin* and *First*.

Comment: @user477343 That's a good demonstration of why you should define this in terms of the other elements. The rule should seem meaningful even in the total absence of the odd-one-out. The set {Below, Blot, demos, First, Gloss, Begin, Pages} would never make you guess at "things that aren't food", so that's probably a bad reason.

Comment: Chips is the only word that starts with C-H-I. Whereas Below is not the only word that starts with B. I can pull odd-one-out properties out of thin air too!

Comment: Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1122/

Comment: I suspect that [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62155/40446) provides the other _odd one out_ leaving your other choice the one that fits.

Comment: @Veedrac good point in how i should phrase the properties, will edit that in. Rupert seems to have found the last one too..

Comment: I'm not sure if I can say this as a comment, but somebody else put a suggestion in one, so here I go; "Below" is in an odd one out because it is the only one not below another word. Don't know if this helps.

Comment: @PlanetAlexander As mentioned in the answer, we'll eventually find ways to make a word become the odd one out... we just need to use increasingly specific and convoluted criterias. "The only one not below any other words", "The only one containing W", "The only one numbered with 1", "The only one that says 'below'", etc.

Comment: @votbear Not everything can be converted. Your reason for #5 is not intended, and seems contrived IMO. As to the others, rot13(Tybff vf "gur bayl bar gung vfa'g na vfbtenz". Fgrira'f nccebnpu vf ba gur evtug yvarf ohg abg dhvgr pbeerpg; VEFG naq rtva ner abg jbeqf.)

Comment: @Veedrac rot13(Abg fher jung lbh zrna ol pbagevirq - V guvax univat 3 pbafbanagf va n ebj vf fvzcyr rabhtu, jura bgure jbeqf unir 2 pbafbanagf va n ebj ng zbfg. 

V guvax vqrn sbe 7'f pevgrevn vf gung lbh pna znxr nabgure jbeq ol erzbivat nal yrggre, abg whfg gur svefg. Fb svefg shysvyyf guvf orpnhfr vg pna ghea gb svfg.)

Comment: @votbear "Qbrfa'g unir guerr pbafrphgvir pbafbanagf" qbrfa'g srry yvxr n angheny jbeq cebcregl VZB. Jul guerr engure guna gjb? / Gur nycunorgvpny beqre nethzrag sbe #7 jnf vagraqrq, ohg lbhe vqrn sbe #7 jbexf gbb (gunaxshyyl vg'f erqhaqnag, abg tnzroernxvat). Gurer'f n qvssrerag gnxr ba Fgrira'f vqrn V jnf ybbxvat sbe.

Comment: Generally speaking the level of arbitrariness should be along the lines of "I might be able find a Wikipedia article about the set the other 7 belong to." Eg. [#2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-letter_word) [#3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) [#4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization) [#6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogram) [#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order) [#8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order) (I'll admit #2 is a bad match, but you get the idea).

Comment: Ahh, got it. That's a good criteria to work on, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Below is the only word that is a preposition, maybe that rules it out?

Answer (score 12):

Like Votbear, the first thing I noticed is

> 4 (demos) is the only word not capitalized.

Since my first guess is apparently wrong, my second guess would be

> 2 (Blot) because it is the only word not 5 letters long.

Answer (score 8):

Is

> Chips

an odd one out because

> It doesn't have an [anagram](https://www.wordplays.com/anagram-solver/)?

The others:

> elbow
>  bolt
>  modes
>  frits
>  slogs
>  being
>  gapes

Answer (score 5):

**Answer 1:**

All words apart from $1$, $5$ and maybe $7$ have a special property such that

> if you take out the first letter, the remaining letters is also a word.

---

All words apart from

> Below $\to$ elow $\quad\color{red}{\verb|X|}$
>  Blot $\to$ lot $\quad\color{green}{\checkmark}$
>  Chips $\to$ hips $\quad\color{green}{\checkmark}$
>  demos $\to$ emos (plural for emo) $\quad\color{green}{\checkmark}$
>  First $\to$ irst (not a word, but IRST stands for *Infra-Red Search & Task*) $\quad\color{red}{\verb|X|}$
>  Gloss $\to$ loss $\quad\color{green}{\checkmark}$
>  Begin $\to$ egin (apparently is a word according to Scrabble and Wikipedia, but not sure) $\quad\color{orange}{?}$
>  Pages $\to$ ages $\quad\color{green}{\checkmark}$

---

> If we consider *egin* and *irst* words, justified by their reasons, then the word **Below** is the odd one out of the list.

---

**Answer 2:**

All words apart from $2$, $3$ and $6$ have the special property such that

> their third letter is not a vowel (one of the letters: $\color{green}{\verb|a|}$, $\color{green}{\verb|e|}$, $\color{green}{\verb|i|}$, $\color{green}{\verb|o|}$ and $\color{green}{\verb|u|}$)

---

All words apart from

> $\verb|Be|\color{red}{\verb|l|}\verb|ow|\quad\color{red}{\verb|X|}$
>  $\verb|Bl|\color{green}{\verb|o|}\verb|t|\quad\,\,\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$
>  $\verb|Ch|\color{green}{\verb|i|}\verb|ps|\quad\color{green}{\checkmark}$
>  $\verb|de|\color{red}{\verb|m|}\verb|os|\quad\color{red}{\verb|X|}$
>  $\verb|Fi|\color{red}{\verb|r|}\verb|st|\quad\color{red}{\verb|X|}$
>  $\verb|Gl|\color{green}{\verb|o|}\verb|ss|\quad\color{green}{\checkmark}$
>  $\verb|Be|\color{red}{\verb|g|}\verb|in|\quad\color{red}{\verb|X|}$
>  $\verb|Pa|\color{red}{\verb|g|}\verb|es|\quad\color{red}{\verb|X|}$

---

Given that out of words $2, 3$ and $6$, we have that $3$ is the only word with a different vowel; i.e., it has $\color{green}{\verb|i|}$ and the others have $\color{green}{\verb|o|}$. Therefore, the odd one out is

> $$\boxed{\color{green}{3} \,}$$

and thus the word **Chips** is the odd one out.

Comment: This is close to the final clue, but you're not *quite* there.

Comment: @Veedrac Thank you for the problem, though. It was a tough one :)

Comment: @Veedrac I edited my answer by adding another possible answer inside it :)

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> 7. Begin

because

> The list is in alphabetical order except for "begin"

Answer (score 4):

Partial solution in addition to Steven Irrgang's answer:

> 6. Gloss is the only one with double letters

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> #5 because it is the only word that does not begin with a 'B' or end with an 'S'

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answers, the thing that makes #1 the odd one out is the property that:

> It's last letter is not enunciated when spoken. 'Below' is pronounced 'Belo'.

Comment: This wasn't intended :S.

Comment: LOL :-) @Veedrac

Comment: FWIW this isn't true for everybody (not true for me for instance, at least not entirely).

Comment: Very fair point @StevenIrrgang - you're right that regional pronunciation differences result in different pronunciations.

Answer (score 2):

Begin is the only verb and also the only one that can't be combined in a meaningful way with another word on the list: you can make eg. "First Pages" or "Below Blot", etc., but "Begin Blot" and others don't make sense.

Comment: This isn't intended. I don't see "Begin Chips" being much more or less clear than, say, "First Chips" or "Gloss Chips".

Comment: @Veedrac I didn't mean that you could combine any noun with any adjective, but  you can combine at least one adjective with at least one of the nouns for the rest of the words. :) at any rate I understand this is not the right answer

Comment: So is Gloss a noun or an adjective? ;)

Comment: @Veedrac whichever you prefer it would still work ;)

Comment: To say "begin" is the only verb is to gloss over the ways other words could be used as verbs.

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Begin

Because:

> The word's value is a prime number 37. 
>  if A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, etc 
>  Below  =  57   (2 + 5 + 12 + 15 + 23) 
>  Blot   =  49   (2 + 12 + 15 + 20) 
>  Chips  =  55   (3 + 8 + 9 + 16 + 19) 
>  demos  =  56   (4 + 5 + 13 + 15 + 19) 
>  First  =  72   (6 + 9 + 18 + 19 + 20) 
>  Gloss  =  72   (7 + 12 + 15 + 19 + 19) 
>  Begin  =  37   (2 + 5 + 7 + 9 + 14) 
>  Pages  =  48   (16 + 1 + 7 + 5 + 19)

Comment: Very creative! $(+1)$

Answer (score 2):

Answer

> 7. Begin

Because

> All words can have a single letter removed and a completely new word can be formed without needing to rearrange the remaining letters
>
> 1. Below - remove the **E** --> *Blow*
>
> 2. Blot - remove the **L** --> *Bot*, or remove the **B** --> *Lot*
>
> 3. Chips - remove the **C** --> *Hips*
>
> 4. demos - remove the **D** --> *Emos*
>
> 5. First - remove the **R** --> *Fist*
>
> 6. Gloss - remove the **G** --> *Loss*
>
> 7. Begin - *no single letter removed results in new word*
>
> 8. Pages - remove the **P** --> *Ages*

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! You'll want to hide your answer in spoiler tags to avoid giving it away for anyone who wants to try the puzzle themselves, but other than that, I think you've nailed it! Good first answer!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the [Tour]!) How does your answer add to the identical ones already given? You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.

Comment: @Rubio I don't believe this is a duplicate of any existing answers, it's similar to [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62156/31839) but with a different answer and subtly different reasoning. In fact, based on the OP's comment on that answer, I'm inclined to believe this is the intended solution.

Comment: @F1Krazy [This answer](/a/62150) notes this property, as does [this one](/a/62153).

Comment: @Rubio I did look at the previous answers. What clued me in was a particular answer given that said removing the first letter resulted in a new word, but not every case was correct. The OP said that answer was close but not quite there. This lead me to alter that answer by saying removing any letter, not just the first, results in a new word, except for 'Begin'. I believe that this makes it not a repeat answer, but a more informed one by additional clues from OP.

Comment: This wasn't intended but I have no problems with it since it doesn't break the puzzle as a whole (and it's a neat trick). I will say that there is a *different* way of slightly changing the "remove first letter" thing that I thought would be much easier to find than it seems to be.

Comment: @Geebuskryst I understand that you saw one answer talking about first letters and altered it to create an answer of your own, different from that one. But forget about the first-letter answer. The answer you ended up with is ALSO already given, in the two other answers I linked earlier. Your answer duplicates (part of) those answers and adds nothing new, so it is entirely duplicative.

Answer (score 2):

> Below - Starts with **B**
>  Blot - Starts with **B**
>  Chips - Ends with **S**
>  demos - Ends with **S**
>  First - Neither Starts with **B** or Ends with **S**
>  Gloss - Ends with **S**
>  Begin - Starts with **B**
>  Pages - Ends with **S**

The Anwser is :

> First

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I'm afraid that answer has [already been given](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62214/31839). Please try to ensure that you're not posting a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How has nobody mentioned that Below is the only preposition?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Remember to place your answer in spoiler tags. For more info, take the Tour!

Answer (score 1):

> 7.Begin
>  Maybe because it interrupts the alphabetical order?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  How does your answer add to the identical ones already given? You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.

Comment: ..Thanks for the suggestion @Rubio as am new to this . I come across the same answer with the different reason.So i thought of posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess, which may be an alternative.

> Looking at the list that seems variously different, I thought it 
>  has something to do with the words itself, so I used the classical 
>  word to number test. 
>  With a = 1, b = 2, ..., z = 26, here's the sums of each letters in word: 
>  
>  below = 57 
>  blot  = 49 
>  chips = 55 
>  demos = 56 
>  first = 72 
>  gloss = 72 
>  begin = 37 
>  pages = 48 
>  
>  The obvious one seen (out of all other "uniqueness" possibilities) is that first and gloss have the same sum. But the answer cannot be two as it says cross the odd one out, so there must be another way to differentiate the two words and still make it the odd one out. 
>  ...Or perhaps there is a reason why the title is "Your first guess is wrong", which crosses out the word first and leaves us with gloss.

(Seeing how demos is the only wordwhich doesn't begin with capital letters and how blot only has 4 letters, I assumed these are traps and tried finding another method)
Edit: Guess I really have to scroll through the answers, I didn't think someone else would use this method haha.

> Yeah, there are also other characteristics that points out to uniqueness, Guest's answer says 37 is a prime number, making begin the answer, chips has number 55, the only repeated digit, blot has 49 the only square number, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please remember to place your answer in spoiler tags. For more info, take the tour!

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at some potential possibilities I noticed

> It could potentially have a common theme of books
>  It could be related to the order they appear and show
>
> `Below` // Look at the one below this (#2)
>
> `Blot` // This one is only four characters and the others are 5, or ink blots may appear on books
>
> `Chips`
>
> `demos` // This starts with lowercase while others don't. Maybe something to do with books?
>
> `First` // Look at first #1
>
> `Gloss` // Often the covers of books have gloss
>
> `Begin` // You should start here and then go...?
>
> `Pages` // Books have pages, it seems this goes in some kind of order